# chrome.storage.sync limits vs. Google Keep

Tags: google-chrome-extension, storage, google-keep

I understand the limitations of QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM and QUOTA_BYTES when using chrome.storage.sync.  I'm finding them quite limiting for a annotated history related extension I am writing.  I understand that local storage could avoid this problem, but I need a user to be able to maintain their data as they move to other devices or someday replace their machine.  My question is - are their other storage methods to get around this?  What about Google Keep?  It is an extension, but it appears capable of a "unlimited" storage of notes, or at least far more than the limitations of chrome.storage.sync.  Is it simply not playing by the same rules, or are there other methods I could be using?  Currently I'm concatenating information into large strings in javascript and storing these using chrome.storage.sync.  Then parsing that information later as my database.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Such extensions usually utilize an external service like dropbox, gdrive, mega, and so on. You can also compress the data using LZString or similar js library into a smaller UTF16 string. In any case extensions can't escape the limits of chrome.storage.sync, there's no magical method. If there were it'd be a superhuge hole in google's security which would be already fixed.

Comment: @wOxxOm - Thank you for the LZString tip.  I think I can greatly reduce my space by simplifying what I'm storing, breaking up my database into multiple blocks to make better use of QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM and QUOTA_BYTES, and utilizing LZString.  LZString will be a big help - thanks for that tip!

Comment: Here's a [usually] much faster fork: [LZString-unsafe](https://github.com/openstyles/lz-string-unsafe).